# Bootstrap mobile dropdown parent link issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following JS to make my bootstrap v3 navigation expand on hover.

I have done this so that the parent link can be a link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        jQuery(function($) {
 $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
 $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();


}, function() {
 $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();


});


$('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function(){
 location.href = this.href;
 });


});
</script>
```

I have an issue on mobiles though, where you click on the parent link and you momentarily for a split second see the children links - but you go straight to the parent link... so you don't have the ability to choose a child link below the parent.

Site: http://crawfordtech.fastnetstaging.co.uk

The parent link in question is called "Solutions".

Any ideas what can be done?

Comment: Now you know why bootstrap doesn't use the hover event. If you want it to work well on mobile, you'll have to move the parent link to a child element.

Comment: I thought there might be some sort of double click JS for mobiles :(

Comment: I suppose you could, but it's a confusing design in touch if you were to do it that way. Better to use a child element.

Comment: I think the easiest thing would be to expand all links in mobile view... never mind

Comment: Blazemonger,
That is why you need to use gumby framework. It is much better at handling this and is already built into the framework. No adding jquery just to make a drop down work. That is the craziest thing i have heard of. It might work good for twitter but is not user friendly.

Comment: Hi did you ever resolve this issue? i am experiencing the exact same

Comment: Hi Paul ... you can use the following script before your closing </html>: 
<script>
 jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
  var location = jQuery(this).attr('href');
  window.location.href = location;
  return false;
  });
 });
 </script>

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap it in a condition, so it'll runs when u need it
I just copy pasta'd from a previous project so ignore or feel free to use the script that is inside. it also makes drop downs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//boostrap hover script
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
if ($(document).width() > 800){
(function(e,d,b){var a=0;var f=null;var c={x:0,y:0};e("[data-toggle]").closest("li").on("mouseenter",function(g){if(f){f.removeClass("open")}d.clearTimeout(a);f=e(this);a=d.setTimeout(function(){f.addClass("open")},b)}).on("mousemove",function(g){if(Math.abs(c.x-g.ScreenX)>4||Math.abs(c.y-g.ScreenY)>4){c.x=g.ScreenX;c.y=g.ScreenY;return}if(f.hasClass("open")){return}d.clearTimeout(a);a=d.setTimeout(function(){f.addClass("open")},b)}).on("mouseleave",function(g){d.clearTimeout(a);f=e(this);a=d.setTimeout(function(){f.removeClass("open")},b)})})(jQuery,window,200);
}});
</script>
```